# iOS testing: "Reset Eligibility" does not appear in iOS Sandbox settings

Tags: ios, testing, app-store-connect, sandbox

I want to test in-app purchase Introductory pricing eligibility as required by Apple when setting up free trials.  Apple evidently has a [Reset Eligibility feature](https://www.revenuecat.com/blog/storekit-testing-in-xcode) that is supposed to show up to make this easier (and so the developer doesn't have to create a different sandbox account for every test iteration).

This button doesn't appear at all though, under Settings -> App Store -> Manage Sandbox Account.  ("Read Receipts" option doesn't appear either, contrary to the picture at that link.)  Any idea why?

I've tried checking the Sandbox Settings page both when the test user is subscribed and after cancellation.  I'm on the latest iOS (14.4.2).  Here's what I see:

[image: 2MR Plus Sandbox]

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, filed a bug report with Apple